# Apple LLVM 5.0 error when building

Tags: ios, xcode5

Upon creating a new project I named it o-golfer ( same as my project name )
Then I modified the Identity name to Application

Now when building it again, I get the Apple LLVM 5.0 error, as the cached precompiled header is trying to find again 
Is there a way  to clear and rebuild this cached header ?
I already tried to clean and build again the project ... same error

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/yves/Developpement/iOS7/OPTIMAL/o-golfer/o-golfer/o-golfer-Prefix.pch'
```

Here is the error log :

```
ProcessPCH /Users/yves/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/o-golfer-cbxwkyokboekvvbscnyxjekgcqyf/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/o-golfer-Prefix-dnguhwlesygrvffouxoeiklsfygm/o-golfer-Prefix.pch.pch o-golfer/o-golfer-Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/yves/Developpement/iOS7/OPTIMAL/o-golfer
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/
...

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/yves/Developpement/iOS7/OPTIMAL/o-golfer/o-golfer/o-golfer-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you tried "Clean Build Folder", which is accessed by holding down the option key? (i.e. Command-shift-option-K)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure the "Prefix Header" build setting (to get to this, click on your project file in the navigator on the left, then go into the "Build Settings" tab) is set to the correct file name.

Comment: hey i have same problem ..please mention complete step

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, make sure you change the prefix header in your project target and in your "app_name" target and "app_tests" target as well, as one of these being different will still throw the error.  Hope this helps ;)